# Switching recipients email address by user selecttion [Laravel]

Tags: laravel

I made contact form using Laravel. It work fine. I would like to add function that when user select below selectbox. Our recipients's email address and email from name changes.  I wrote below however switching doesn't work. Could you teach me right code please?

Here is blade file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p><label class="col-sm-6 control-label">area</label></p>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="branch">
            <option selected>select</option>
            <option value="usa">usa</option>
            <option value="india">india</option>
            <option value="eu">EU</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is controller:

```
if(isset($requrest->branch)) {
    switch ($request->branch) {
        case 'usa':
            $request['email'] = 'usa@mywebsite.com';
            $request['from_name'] = 'usa mail';

        case 'india':
            $request['email'] = 'india@mywebsite.com';
            $request['from_name'] = 'india mail';
                    
        case 'eu':
            $request['email'] = 'eu@mywebsite.com';
            $request['from_name'] = 'eu mail';
            break;
    }
} 

\Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
    'to' => 'main@mywebsite.com',
    'to_name' => 'contact mail',
    'from'  => 'contact@mywebsite.com',
    'from_name' => 'main mail',
    'subject' => 'Mail ['.$request->name.']'.$request->No.'',
    'name' => $request->name,
    'branch' => $request->branch,
    'phone' => $request->phone,
    'message' => $request->message
], 'from'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, just a few things to tweak.

`$request` is already a Request object, so better not to try to use or modify it with extra data like `$request['email']`.  Safer to use some other variable, maybe something like:

```
case 'usa':
    $to = 'usa@mywebsite.com';
    $from_name = 'usa mail';
```

Next, your `switch` code is missing `break`s.  [From the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.

You need to add a `break` after each case:

```
switch ($request->branch) {
    case 'usa':
        $to = 'usa@mywebsite.com';
        $from_name = 'usa mail';
        break;

    case 'india':
        $to = 'india@mywebsite.com';
        $from_name = 'india mail';
        break;

    case 'eu':
        $to = 'eu@mywebsite.com';
        $from_name = 'eu mail';
        break;
}
```

Last, you need to actually *use* the variables you set up in your Mail code.  Right now you have `'to' => 'main@mywebsite.com',`, which is going to be the same every time, no matter what the user chose.  Use the variables you just set up instead:

```
\Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact([
    'to'        => $to,
    ...
    'from_name' => $from_name,
    ...
```

#### UPDATE

If you're still having trouble, try splitting things up into simpler steps that you can test.  Eg try creating your contact first:

```
$contact = new \App\Mail\Contact([
    'to'        => $to,
    ...
    'from_name' => $from_name,
    ...
]);

// Check your contact looks OK?
dd($contact);

// Can you save it OK?  Does this work, and if so, does the record 
// in the DB look OK?
$contact->save();

// If $contact looks good, move to testing the next step.  This code
// does not look right?
\Mail::send($contact, 'from');

// Mail::send() would normally look something like this:
$data = ['contact' => $contact]; // you can now use $contact in your view
\Mail::send('message-view', $data, function($message) use ($contact) {
    $message->to($contact->to);
    $message->from($contact->from, $contact->from_name);
    $message->subject($contact->subject);
});
```

The last line does not look right, are you sure that is working?  I am not sure which version of Laravel you are using, but `Mail::send()` should take 3 parameters: the message blade view, an array of data to pass to the view, and a closure where you can set subject etc.  [Here's a link to the docs for Laravel 5.2, where `Mail::send()` is documented](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail) - in later versions of Laravel things changed a bit and `Mail::send()` is not documented any more, though maybe it still works, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explaination is amazing! that's very kind! Thank you!
May I ask one thing? I tried your code but I couldn't switch email address. I can send email with no error. I tried dd() but I can only see inside of  Contact::create($request->all()) which goes mysql.
I don't know how to to look inside of \Mail::send(new \App\Mail\Contact. Could you teach me little more?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: @bluetail Does my answer help?

Comment: Sorry for late and Thank you very much for keep helping me. I'm beginner Could you wait for a while? I have been trying!

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!!! I had been mistake setting email address value. your whole answer was really helped me. Thank you again!